# Rails 4: Delete button posting to the index action.

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, link-to

I am not using JS turbo links in my Rails app for several important reasons. I am having problems with one delete button:

```
<% if current_user?(comment.user) %>
    <%= link_to "delete", micropost_response_comment_path(@micropost, @response, comment), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "You sure?" }, :class =>    "btn btn-default btn-xs delete" %>
  <% end %>
```

Here is the error - its posting to the index action of the comments_controller.

```
 {"controller"=>"comments", "action"=>"index", "micropost_id"=>"impedit-ipsam-maxime-voluptatem-quis-vitae-perferendis-voluptatem-quia-minus-officia-dolorem-aut-placeat-tempora-earum-optio-quam-saepe-velit-871c1ab8-e282-441b-b610-4d2937c9aeef", "response_id"=>"38"}
```

All the other delete buttons and destroy functionality on my app works. I can't see any problem here and I am not sure what else to add - I am sure more info is needed but not sure what...

If you have a suggestion and need more info please let me know.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the controller and action as follows:

```
<% if current_user?(comment.user) %>
  <%= link_to "delete", { controller: "comments", action: "delete", micropost: @micropost, response: @response, comment: comment}, data: { confirm: "You sure?" }, class: "btn btn-default btn-xs delete" %>
<% end %>
```

Otherwise, you may have a routing issue.

Answer (score 0):

the error is not showing your 3rd argument: "comment".
That is missing.
Can you identify why?
Also the error itself is not displayed. Can you select more text and bring in here?

Is that error being raised before or after the "delete" action from the controller?
Has the record already been deleted and the controller is leading you to the index correctly?
What is the full error message?
What is your "delete" action in the controller?
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found the error and its really a string of errors that one would not have thought of. Not sure if anyone can learn from this but here goes....

Comments belong to Response which belongs to Micropost.

I had

```
 belongs_to :response, dependent: :destroy
```

in my comments model rather than the other way around, therefore as I destroyed a comment, its parent was also destroyed.

In my destroy method in the comments controller I had a redirect

```
   format.html { redirect_to micropost_response_comments_path(@micropost, @response) }
```

after the destroy, which was now impossible because @response was always destroyed with it......

Calamity of errors. Thanks for your time guys...

Message is:

IF YOU HAVE STRANGE BEHAVIOURS OCCURRING WHEN DELETING OBJECTS, MAKE SURE YOUR RELATIONSHIPS FOR THAT MODEL, ITS PARENTS AND ITS CHILDREN ARE CORRECT.